# Component must be wrapped with <Container.Provider>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, looker-studio

I have below app.js

```
import { sdk } from "../src/helpers/CorsSession";
 import { Query, Visualization } from "@looker/visualizations";
 import { DataProvider } from "@looker/components-data";
 import { ComponentsProvider } from "@looker/components";
 
 function App() {
   return (
     <>
       <h1>Get started with Looker visualization components</h1>
       <ComponentsProvider>
         <DataProvider sdk={sdk}>
           {/* Change this query slug to match your query slug */}
           <Query query="97f65408-be03-4e88-a2ec-99b9387ba9f6">
             <Visualization />
           </Query>
         </DataProvider>
       </ComponentsProvider>
     </>
   );
 }
 
 export default App;
```

It throws error

> Component must be wrapped with <Container.Provider>

What I am doing wrong here

Thanks